# My extension has been stolen and is now being sold for lower price

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

I am selling a Magento extension inside Magento Connect. Somebody bought it, copied entire code, just renamed it and now he is selling it in Magento Connect for lower price. My licence does not allow that.

This was my best selling extension, I put so much effort to make it perfect and now this clearly lowered my sale.

Do I have any chance? The person is from Asia and I am from Europe. It would be probably nearly impossible to make any legal action unless I don't invest USD 10k+ for legal adviser. What options do I have left?

Comment: i think you have no chance, sorry for that :-/

Comment: This is a legal advice question. Get in touch with legal counsel. There is nothing else besides attempting to notify the public that it's a rip. Other forms of retaliation will have karmic rebound and in the end accomplish nothing but personal damage.

Comment: That won't work, if they took it in the first place they don't give a damn. On a business view there is pretty much nothing you can do as the cost/time balance is against you - and they know it. Sometimes you selectively have to fight fire with fire - if you can't gain on the business side occassionally you have to take the opposite view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is the case we will pull it from Connect. Email me at ben.marks@magento.com.

Comment: You made my day so much better with this answer! Thank you, I just sent you e-mail.

Comment: @benmarks good job. appreciated

Answer (score 0):

That's great to hear that. I think you can also contact that developer and ask him to remove the extension from his store. If you can prove that extension was stolen from you, you can report it to payment gateways which he use (like Paypal...).